# iPad is stuck in Guided Access

Tags: password, guided-access

My daughter accidentally turned on the Guided access, and the dilemma here is that we forgot the password, and we can't turn off the iPad to reboot, because it is stuck in app which she is using. How can I remove the Guided Access ?

Answer (score 1):

That is a dilemma. If you know the password to access the iPad itself, hold the home and power button down until the iPad reboots.

When it starts, it should not boot back into Guided Access and you shouldn't have to remember the password.

Comment: I tried it and its still the same...

Comment: I just tested it and it worked great. Are you holding the power AND home buttons down **together** until you see the Apple logo?

Comment: I tried it the second time and it worked! thank you so much!